# Authorize-attributed controller returns 401

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I have a .net core api that on authenticate generates a JWT token that should be used for calling controllers with the 'authorize' attribut. Although after creating the token, the controller responds with 401 every time.

I've searched for tutorials just to the the basics in place, and my code is almost identical with most guides.

Controller endpoint that requires token;

```
 // GET: api/Tournaments
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetTournaments()
        {
            return Ok(_context.Tournaments.Select(t => _mapper.Map<TournamentDto>(t)));
        }
```

Authenticate endpoint;

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModelDto model)
        {
            var user = await _authService.Login(model);
            if (user == null)
                return BadRequest();

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                {
                    new Claim("UserID", user.UserId.ToString())
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials =
                    new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_appSettings.JWT_Secret)),
                        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
            return Ok(new {token});

        }
```

Startup.cs

```
var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["ApplicationSettings:JWT_Secret"]);

            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = false;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });
```

The controller should return a list of tournaments, but now returning 401. Am I missing something? My guts tells me that something is wrong with the creation of the JWT token, although I am out of ideas to test.

Best regards,
Fredrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the order of

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseMvc();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

to

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseMvc();
```

and everything now works as intended.

Case closed. Thank you for your answer Zach.